# Change a background-image of a <section> in CSS, depending on season (spring, summer, autumn, winter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript countdown to a specific date and I'd like to change a background-image for a section depends on what season it is (spring, summer, autumn, winter)

4 Seasons timeline:
Spring (March to May)
Summer (June to August)
Autumn (September to November)
Winter (December to February)

I'd declare a specific date in my script code, its countdown ends in october 15, 2020, I can't think of any logic yet, so im asking for help :) Thank you!

here is my javascript code:

```
function dateCountdown() {
    const second = 1000,
        minute = second * 60,
        hour = minute * 60,
        day = hour * 24;

    //set the timer here
    let countDown = new Date('Oct 15, 2020 00:00:00').getTime(),
        x = setInterval(function () {

            let now = new Date().getTime(),
                distance = countDown - now;

            document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
                document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
                document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
                document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

            //do something later when date is reached
            //if (distance < 0) {
            //  clearInterval(x);
            //  'IT'S TIME!;
            //}

        }, second)
}
```

and here is the HTML Code:

```
      <section class="section-countdown">
        <h2>THIS CONGRESS BEGINS IN</h2>
        <ul class="countdown">
            <li>
              <span id="days"></span>
              <p class="days_ref">DAYS</p>
            </li>
            <li class="seperator">:</li>
            <li>
              <span id="hours"></span>
              <p class="hours_ref">HOURS</p>
            </li>
            <li class="seperator">:</li>
            <li>
              <span id="minutes"></span>
              <p class="minutes_ref">MINUTES</p>
            </li>
            <li class="seperator">:</li>
            <li>
              <span id="seconds"></span>
              <p class="seconds_ref">SECONDS</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
```

Comment: You can use date functions like `.getMonth()` to the current month, then figure out which season that month falls in, then apply a background dynamically to the `section`

Comment: Don't forget that if you're in the north part of the globe the season are the way you listed it here, but if you're in the south winter is swapped with summer and fall with spring

Comment: i will try to do that thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using DOM you able to change the image background in such way that (sample image link) and you have to further style it to fit your section:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("section-countdown")[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6Ir9FSUsaLA/maxresdefault.jpg")';
```

I accessed the section by using `getElementsByClassName` but I suggest you to assign an **id** for this section if this is the only section to use DOM to *point* specifically to this section instead of using `getElementsByClassName` as it returns objects although there is only one class.
For the method to distinguish the seasons, I prefer to use `getMonth()` from `date()` in which that :

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
if(month < 3){
//spring
}else if(month > 2 && month < 6){
//summer
}.....
```

And you may set the countdown function in a **interval** way such as `setInterval()`

Take a look about the [getMonth()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) and also the [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) functions.

Comment: I have tried this and this works for me! thank a lot!

Comment: @セアンデエ welcome and you can try to find more about date functions since seasons range is always changing year by year

Answer (score 3):

You could try something as the following to get the season:

```
function getSeason() {
  var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  if (currentMonth === 12 || currentMonth === 1 || currentMonth === 2)
    return "winter";
  else if (currentMonth >= 3 && currentMonth <= 5)
    return "spring";
  else if (currentMonth >= 6 && currentMonth <= 8)
    return "summer";
  else if (currentMonth >= 9 && currentMonth <= 11)
    return "fall";
  return ""
}
```

And then create a function as the following to set the background image on your desired element:

```
function setBackground() {
  var image = "";
  switch (getSeason()) {
    case "winter":
      image = imageurlhere;
      break;
    case "spring":
      image = imageurlhere;
      break;
    case "summer":
      image = imageurlhere;
      break;
    case "fall":
      image = imageurlhere;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  document.getElementByClassName("section-countdown").style.backgroundImage = 'url(image)';
}
```

EDIT: my bad getMonth() is zero based, I've changed it above.

Comment: glad I could help!